# Hard coding in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have an assignment to submit in this week. And I did not understand this jargon "hardcode". It's my first class in C++ , where my professor asked me to demonstrate a simple math operation. By using all the 9 integral data types and a single "hard coded" value. Can some one please explain what hardcoding is? I am new to c++ and would appreciate if some one can throw some light on this.

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding

Answer (score 0):

Basically it means that the value is set inside the source code. If you asked for the variable it's not hardcoded, but if you say int x = 5; then x has been hardcoded to 5.